# Concurrent bidirectional dictionary

Tags: c#, thread-safety, hash-map

I've been agonizing over this for an hour or two. I require a bidirectional dictionary that was thread safe. From what I understand about dictionaries, they're thread safe when being read from, but no so much when being written to. I've tried to write this code snippet to my understanding of correct, but a review would be excellent if possible.

```
class ConcurrentBidirectionalDictionary<TKey,UKey>
{
    private Dictionary<TKey, UKey> BackingDictionary;

    public ConcurrentBidirectionalDictionary()
    {
        BackingDictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, UKey>();
    }

    //Adding to dictionaries is not thread-safe ergo, lock when adding
    private readonly object _SyncLock = new object();
    public void Add(TKey item1, UKey item2)
    {
        if (!BackingDictionary.ContainsKey(item1) && !BackingDictionary.ContainsValue(item2))
        {
            lock (_SyncLock)
            {
                if (!BackingDictionary.ContainsKey(item1) && !BackingDictionary.ContainsValue(item2))
                {
                    BackingDictionary.Add(item1, item2);
                }
                else
                {
                    ThrowNewDuplicateKeyException(item1, item2);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ThrowNewDuplicateKeyException(item1, item2);
        }
    }

    private void ThrowNewDuplicateKeyException(TKey item1, UKey item2)
    {
        if (BackingDictionary.ContainsKey(item1) && BackingDictionary.ContainsValue(item2))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Duplicate Keys not allowed", "item1, item 2", null);
        }
        else if (BackingDictionary.ContainsKey(item1))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Duplicate Keys not allowed", "item1", null);
        }
        else if (BackingDictionary.ContainsValue(item2))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Duplicate Keys not allowed", "item 2", null);
        }
    }

    //Reading is thread safe, no lock needed
    public TKey GetFromUKey(UKey UKey)
    {
        var Record = BackingDictionary.FirstOrDefault(x => EqualityComparer<UKey>.Default.Equals(x.Value, UKey));
        if (Record.Equals(default(KeyValuePair<TKey,UKey>)))
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException($"Unable to find UKey {UKey}");
        }
        return Record.Key;
    }

    public UKey GetFromTKey(TKey TKey)
    {
        return BackingDictionary[TKey];
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a thought, might be useful to look at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Gareth I'd considered it, but I also need to look up items in reverse.

Comment: @Sidney - reviewing your code - for me it's not entirely clear why you have a primary and reverse dictionary?

Comment: so you could have U:"alpha", T:"beta", and U:"beta", T:"alpha"  as 2 distinct pairs, but you can't have U:"alpha", T:"beta" and U:"beta", T:"gamma"

Comment: If the latter is not valid, then a single inner dictionary is only required. ie adding both [alpha] = beta and [beta] = alpha

Comment: @BKSpurgeon I based it mainly of [Jon Skeets answer to a similar problem that didn't require thread safety](http://stackoverflow.com/a/255630/2254971). I could do a reverse lookup, but this way I can utilize a "has key" for both.

Comment: I hadn't considered the case of @Gareth's third comment. I will adjust.

Comment: oh what a shame, @Dmitry Nogin deleted a really neat c#6? Map implementation. I was enjoying that.

Comment: Sorry, it was not atomic :) Fixed.

Comment: What about just adding both T and U, then you don't have to look up one in the values. `if ( TryAdd(T,U) ) { Add(U,T)) }` Then you avoid the need to get GetT and GetU, and can have a single Get Method

Answer (score 4):

It is better to use `CouncurrentDictionary` to reduce [lock contention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)#Granularity):

```
class Map<X, Y>
{
    public X this[Y y]
    {
        get { return YX[XY[YX[y]]]; } // Ensure Set completion
        set { Set(value, y); }
    }

    public Y this[X x]
    {
        get { return XY[x]; }
        set { Set(x, value); }
    }

    void Set(X x, Y y)
    {
        if (!YX.GetOrAdd(y, x).Equals(x))
            throw new InvalidOperationException();

        if (!XY.GetOrAdd(x, y).Equals(y))
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    ConcurrentDictionary<X, Y> XY { get; } = new ConcurrentDictionary<X, Y>();
    ConcurrentDictionary<Y, X> YX { get; } = new ConcurrentDictionary<Y, X>();
}
```

Comment: Using two dictionaries instead of one definitely makes things easier. What bothers me is `YX[XY[YX[y]]]` as it greatly increases lookup time. If you want to ensure something - I think you should do it once the item is added or removed, not every time it is read. Also your code won't throw if the same key-vlaue pair added multiple times and it won't work for `Map<int, int>` (original code does not have those issues).

Comment: 1)`O(3f(n)) = O(f(n))` - it is usually nothing to optimize here. I cannot see a way to ensure that update is atomic (symmetry of operations) without checking other dictionary. 2, 3) Yep, agree, thanks (`TryAdd` should help reproducing the behavior of the original code).

Comment: I wasn't talking about complexity, I was talking about performance. Decent lookup times is one of the major reasons people use dictionaries in the first place. You take this advantage away. And why can't you check the other dictionary, when you update?..

Comment: We will need to lock other dictionary to prevent racing condition then. It creates point of contention, which is usually influences performance much more than executing a very cheap operation three times.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have some misconceptions regarding thread safety. Check out [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) about `Dictionary`. Thread Safety section states:

> A Dictionary can support multiple readers concurrently,
>   as long as the collection is not modified. Even so, enumerating
>   through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe procedure. In
>   the rare case where an enumeration contends with write accesses, the
>   collection must be locked during the entire enumeration. To allow the
>   collection to be accessed by multiple threads for reading and writing,
>   you must implement your own synchronization.

This is because when you write to dictionary it can,for example, increase the size of underlying collections or reorganize internal "buckets" where items are stored. Those operation will move items around which can break a concurrent read operation in unpredictable way. Enumerations on the other hand will throw straight away, if you modify the collection during enumeration process.

The bottom line is: your `GetFromTKey` (read) and `GetFromUKey` (enumeration) are not thread safe. You must synchronize them with your `Add` method if you want to read and write concurrently.